# SSH could not find hidden user folder

Tags: linux, ssh, key-authentication

I generated a public/private rsa key pair to access the remote host via ssh without entering the password, everything worked fine till I made the user's folder hidden (Added . to name */home/.user*). Now while connecting with SSH it can't find the public key to connect to and asks for a password.

```
ssh -i my_private_key user@x.x.x.x
```

Once I connect using the password it says:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/user: No such file or directory
```

P.S Did not change `.sshd_config` file. So how to fix it so it works with a hidden folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/etc/passwd` so it points to `/home/.user` also?

Answer (score 3):

Users have their own home directories. When you login via ssh and you establish a successfull connection, the user's session starts in his own home directory. If the directory is missing, you get the error you have. Furthermore, if you moved the /home/user directory, it contains the .ssh directory which has your public key defined inside the **authorized_keys** file.

You could try and change the home directory to the "hidden" one using something like

```
usermod -d /home/.user user
```

This will make ssh read the public key, and start the session properly. But the "hidden" home directory would still be visible in **/etc/passwd** for example.